# Why can't I use wildcard with methods receiving a parameterized argument?

Tags: java, generics, wildcard, parameterized

For example, I use a method `Measure.doubleValue(Unit<?> unit)` which returns the `double` value of a measurement, expressed in the specified `Unit`. If I pass a `Unit<?>` variable to it, I get the still very cryptic (to me) error message:

> `The method
>   doubleValue(Unit<capture#27-of ?>) in
>   the type Measurable<capture#27-of ?>
>   is not applicable for the arguments
>   (Unit<capture#28-of ?>)`

I would appreciate if someone could explain what that `#27-of ?` (or any other number) means, and if there is an elegant way to get rid of this. Thus far, I remove the `<?>` and set the calling method `@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")` (so I pass an unchecked `Unit` instead of a `Unit<?>`) and everything works as desired, but I'm just curious about this, and I feel like suppressing warnings is not a good practice (isn't it a little like empty catch blocks?).

Thanks!

**Edit: Adding some code.**

(I'm sorry, this is quite long, but it explains in details what I'm stuck on.)

I am using [JSR-275](http://jsr-275.kenai.com/apidocs/) [version 0.9.4](http://download.java.net/maven/2/javax/measure/jsr-275/0.9.4/) (most recent).

So... If I write this (very dumb example):

```
Measure measure = Measure.valueOf("3 m");
measure = Measure.valueOf(measure.doubleValue(Unit.valueOf("km")), Unit.valueOf("km"));
System.out.println(measure);
```

It works and prints "0.0030 km". But I get warning "*Measure is a raw type. References to generic type Measure<Q> should be parameterized*" over the first `Measure` occurrence and warning "*Type safety: The method doubleValue(Unit) belongs to the raw type Measurable. References to generic type Measurable<Q> should be parameterized*" over `measure.doubleValue(Unit.valueOf("km"))`.

Seeing these warnings, I thought I could adjust this way (first line only):

```
Measure<Length> measure = Measure.valueOf("3 m");
```

And then I get error message on right part of assignation "*Type mismatch: cannot convert from Measure<capture#1-of ?> to Measure<Length>*". It (Eclipse) offers me to cast the right part to `(Measure&lt;Length>)`. But then I get warning message over the right part "*Type safety: Unchecked cast from Measure<capture#1-of ?> to Measure<Length>*". Fix suggested: `@SuppressWarnings` which I would prefer to avoid (for paranoid reasons I guess).

So, I step back to `Measure measure = Measure.valueOf("3 m");` and try to give wildcard to `Measure`, as obviously, it doesn't know what "3 m" means at this moment. It could be a `Length`, but also a `Mass` or a `Time`. So I get:

```
Measure<?> measure = Measure.valueOf("3 m");
```

And no warning or error on this line; fantastic. But, on the second line:

```
measure = Measure.valueOf(measure.doubleValue(Unit.valueOf("km")), Unit.valueOf("km"));
```

I get and error message for `doubleValue`: "*The method doubleValue(Unit<capture#3-of ?>) in the type Measurable<capture#3-of ?> is not applicable for the arguments (Unit<capture#4-of ?>)*". It suggests to cast `Unit.valueOf("km")` as a `(Unit<?>)`. Fine. Now I get error message at the exact same location: "*The method doubleValue(Unit<capture#3-of ?>) in the type Measurable<capture#3-of ?> is not applicable for the arguments (Unit<capture#5-of ?>)*". Notice that the numbers have changed, so that's not the exact same parameters, but a similar reason. Then it does the exact same suggestion which leads to no change whatsoever in the code, since it has already been done.

So that's what is bugging me. The only way to get it working seems to `@SuppressWarnings` or just ignore them. Isn't it strange?

Comment: Do you have some actual code we can look at? Generics is something that's very much "the devil's in the details".

Comment: I agree with Chris. You might be able to solve your problem by taking a `Unit<Object>` instead of `Unit<?>`, but without code it's hard to say.

Comment: Sorry for the delay, couldn't do faster. I wrote an example code, out of context, as I thought the hundred lines mixed with this in the real life code are not relevant.

Comment: The extra code helped. You definitely should not be suppressing warnings; JSR-275 has gone to great lengths to take advantage of generics. I updated my answer with a solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Does the measure class look something like this?

```
class Measure<T> {

  double doubleValue(Unit<T> unit) {
    ...
  }

}
```

In that case, have a reference type of `Measure<?>` doesn't mean that you are allowed to pass any type of `Unit` to the `doubleValue` method. Rather, it means that the `Measure` instance has an unknown generic type, and it isn't safe to pass a `Unit` to its `doubleValue` method because the compiler cannot ensure that the types are compatible.

A wildcard does *not* mean "any type"; it means "unknown type".

---

**Update:**

The `valueOf(CharSequence)` returns an unknown type of `Measure`—a `Measure<?>`. To convert this safely to the type of `Measure` you expect, you must use the `Measure.asType()` method. Likewise with the target `Unit`, created by the `Unit.valueOf(CharSequence)` method.

```
Measure<?> unknownMeasure = valueOf("3 m");
Unit<?> unknownUnit = Unit.valueOf("km");
Measure<Length> length = unknownMeasure.asType(Length.class);
Unit<Length> kilometer = unknownUnit.asType(Length.class);
length.doubleValue(kilometer);
```

Look at the examples in the `Measure` class documentation. They will provide some additional depth.

Comment: I am not 100 % sure about how these classes really are defined. A problem, with this library, is that we have the latest code, but we can't find the same version API, nor the same version code. Well, yes for the code, but it's not identical to the bytecode classes for some reason... (Some features and method signature are not the same.)

Answer (score 2):

The wildcard in Java generics means "unknown type". Here, you define the `doubleValue()` method as accepting a `Unit<something1>` where the `something1` is not specified by the method. You then pass a value that the caller knows as `Unit<something2>` for some unknown `something2`. The compiler error message means that there is nothing which guarantees that the `something1` and the `something2` designate the same thing.

Try this:

```
<T> double doubleValue(Unit<T> unit)
{
    ...
}
```

which means that `doubleValue()` *does not care* about what `T` is.

Answer (score 1):

To expand on the other (excellent) answers, but be a bit more JSR-275 specific (I'm using it for a project at the moment).

This bit is interesting

> Fix suggested: @SuppressWarnings which I would prefer to avoid (for paranoid reasons I guess).

You're right to be paranoid, but think about it: you're telling the `Measure` class to parse an arbitrary `String`, and return a `Measure` of any type. Obviously in that case you may or may not get a `Measure<Length>` (you might pass "3 kg")  so the only option left to the library is return `Measure<?>`. If you WANT a `Measure<Length>`, then you have to coerce it to one somehow -- this can't possibly be guaranteed safe at compile-time.

In this case, I would argue that @SuppressWarnings is perfectly acceptable, *assuming* you know that the string will always be a valid length. If not, you're delaying an inevitable `ClassCastException` until later, which is pretty bad.

**But** even better (hooray!) JSR-275 does give you a way around this, which pushes the error handling to the 'right' place (at the time of obtaining the `Measure`, not at some point afterwards when it's used). Try

```
Measure<Length> = Measure.valueOf("3 m").asType(Length.class);
```

`asType` returns the appropriate generic version of `Measure`, or fails with an exception if the dimension of the parsed unit is NOT length -- this is almost certainly what you want, right?

I think this solves your problem.

Comment: You're right, `.asType()` would fix the problem. Very good answer indeed.
But, in my case, I still have a problem, because my extension of the JSR-275 library is supporting conversion between different quantities. In the optical domain, for example, we convert between nm, THz, Ky, etc. directly, so I can't force a type to my measures... But that's another story. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I can not reproduce your problem, i.e. the following compiles fine (at least with eclipse):

```
static double doubleValue(Unit<?> unit) {
    return 0;
}

static void bla(Unit<?> u) {
    doubleValue(u);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    doubleValue(new Unit<String>());
}
```